# how to u produce such a vocal effect?

Tags: mixing, vocals, replication

from 0:16 the way he says "We Are" every alternative time, you can hear there's two vocal recordings (of the same voice) saying "arrre" to produce a good effect. It also feels like one recording  said the syllable "are" shorter than the other recording. Is this reverb or something? How do you edit like this? Sorry for such simple language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply multiple takes layered over. You'd simply layer them on separate tracks and mix the backing track lower. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: How many multiple takes/layers would u recommend in such situation, from your experience?